# In Xpages make first field have focus

Tags: xpages

I cannot get the first field (or any) on my Xpage to have focus when a new document is created.

I have entered

dojo.query("input[id$='loc1']")[0].focus();

in the onQueryLoad. I get the error:

Script interpreter error, line=1, col=6: [ReferenceError] 'dojo' not found

I thought basic dojo was loaded. I do not understand how to load dojo.

What is the easiest way to give a field focus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add this code to your XPage

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        try {
            var input = dojo.query("input[type='text']")[0]; 
            input.focus();
            input.selectionEnd = input.selectionStart;
        } catch (e) { }
    ]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

then **first input text field** will get the **focus** and text in field will be **deselected**.

Comment: No it didn't. I added it and none of the fields are in focus. I have an XPage that uses a application layout customer control, and the middle customer control is for entering data. So I put this code in the entry custom control. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Please check in your rendered source page if code is included and what is the first input field of type text. This field has to visible and editable.

Comment: Knut, the problem was that I had a field before the field I wanted to put the focus on. That field is a computed field. When I changed the subscript to [1], it put the focus on the 2nd field. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have picked a serverside script event. Usually you add an OutputScript element and add code like this (off my head might contain typos):

```
        XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
                XSP.byId("#{id:loc1}").focus();
                });
```

Does that work for you?

**Update**

Complete example, works here:

XPage:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
        <xc:LayoutSample>
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xc:focusBaby xp:key="facetMiddle"></xc:focusBaby>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xc:LayoutSample>
    </xp:view>
```

Custom control (where you have the named element, the second in my form)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
        One&#160;
        <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        Two&#160;
        <xp:inputText id="inputText2"></xp:inputText>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
      XSP.getElementById("#{id:inputText2}").focus();
    });]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:scriptBlock>
    </xp:view>
```

What did you do different?

Comment: No it didn't. I added it and none of the fields are in focus. I have an XPage that uses a application layout customer control, and the middle customer control is for entering data. So I put this code in the entry custom control. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Your code worked perfectly as well as the other poster. I did not put the code with the field. I thought it could go at the top. Thank thou for your help.